# How to Use AWS Systems Manager (SSM) for Accessing a RabbitMQ Broker in an AWS VPC Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-vpc, aws-ssm, amazon-mq

I'm currently working on setting up a RabbitMQ broker within an AWS private subnet and accessing it securely using AWS Systems Manager (SSM)

> **Note: working solution:** I have tried with bastion host in public subnet and rabbitmq broker in private subnet and attached the proper security
> group and proxy setting and able access the rabbitmq console in
> firefox browser

below is my ssh port forwarding command

```
ssh -i "poc-rabbitmq-jump-box-2.pem" -N -C -f -D 4444 ec2-user@<ec2-public-address>
```

But want to access using SSM ,Here's what I've tried so far:

I've successfully used SSM to establish port forwarding sessions for other services(RDS) using commands like:

```
aws ssm start-session --target <ssm-managed-instance-id> --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"portNumber":["3306"],"localPortNumber":["1053"],"host":[" remote-database-host-name"]
```

However, when attempting to adapt this approach for RabbitMQ which is in private subnet, I encountered issues. Here's the command I tried:

```
aws ssm start-session --target <ssm-managed-instance-id> --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"portNumber":["443"],"localPortNumber":["5555"],"host":["b-<someid>.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com "]}


rabbitmq web Console url: https://b-<someid>.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
PortNumber tried: 443, 15672
```

The RabbitMQ broker's console URL is: https://b-.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Unfortunately, this approach didn't work as expected, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause of the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to effectively utilize AWS Systems Manager for securely accessing a RabbitMQ broker within a private subnet. Thank you in advance for your assistance!